# Why does "groove" mean "take pleasure in"?

Tags: meaning

The original meaning of "groove" is something like a cave, or as a verb, make a groove.

Why can "groove" mean "take pleasure in" as a verb?

Comment: maybe the grooves in vinyl and the associated pleasure taken from listening to said vinyl?

Comment: *Groovy* and *grooving* both come from *"in the groove"*, an expression used by jazz musicians in the 1930s. See [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=groovy).

Comment: @Brad: Do you mean alcohol by "vinyl"?

Comment: What is GR? @Kris

Comment: General Reference: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142679/why-does-groove-mean-take-pleasure-in?noredirect=1#

Comment: @Tim, no LPs, records, EPs, 45s, etc, etc...

Comment: @Brad: what is LP, EP, 45?

Answer (score 4):

The term *groove*, meaning *to take pleasure in*, probably comes from the term *in the groove* used by jazz musicians, as early as the 1930s. [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=groovy) [says](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=groove&searchmode=none) that the adjective *groovy* (1937) and the slang verb *to groove* (late 1930s<sup>1</sup>) originated with this expression.

This was defined in the book [Swing That Music](http://books.google.com/books?id=2H4sAAAAMAAJ&q=%22in+the+groove%22+music&dq=%22in+the+groove%22+music&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gpm1UtHQE9PMsQTL04KIBw&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAQ), by Louis Armstrong and ‎Horace Gerlach (1936):

> IN THE GROOVE : When carried away or inspired by the music, when playing in exalted spirit and to perfection.

The earliest I can find this usage in Google Books is from [1932](http://books.google.com/books?id=W6w5AAAAIAAJ&q=%22in+the+groove%22+music&dq=%22in+the+groove%22+music&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Qpu1UreKMo_JsQTq7YKQDQ&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBDgK):

> These two have magnificent swing, the rhythm is in-the-groove all the way and the solos, especially clarinet and trombone, are strictly up to par.

which is also about jazz, although note that this time it's just the *rhythm* which is in the groove.

Where does this expression come from? It seems that *"in the groove"* may have been used before this, meaning that you were repeatedly doing the same thing, but (unlike *"in a rut"*) in a positive sense. This snippet comes from the [Journal of American Insurance](http://books.google.com/books?id=OakaAQAAMAAJ&q=%22in+the+groove%22+music&dq=%22in+the+groove%22+music&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_Ji1UoKGLPPJsQSvlIHgDg&ved=0CFMQ6AEwCTge) from 1928:

> "… I envy you the pep you have brought back with you. Pity me if you like; I have had no vacation," I answered him.
>   "Not at all," replied he. "You are in the groove, and running smoothly".

(Note that since this use isn't that much earlier, it might have come from the musical sense, and just been written down sooner.)

<sup>1</sup> the verb *"to groove",* meaning "to make grooves in", is much older.

Answer (score 3):

The edison phonograph was invented in 1877. By 1902, the phonograph industry was growing quickly--over a hundred thousand edison phonographs and  5 million edison-format records had been produced (Leonard DeGraaf, *Confronting the Mass Market: Thomas Edison and the Entertainment Phonograph*,  Business and Economic History Vol. 24 (Fall 1995):89-90), and the word "groove" was being used for recordings (http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=groove, accessed 20140212).

As the phonograph became more familiar to the general public in the early 20th century, the average person would have been increasingly aware of records, and what a record sounded like when it was *not* in the groove--sudden and dissonant--and consider that early "talking" movies often had the audio track playing on a phonograph. The audio joke that is the sound of a skipping or scratching record persists even today in an era when vinyl records are a niche market.

As such, it is conjecture, but a plausible one, that "in the groove" was adopted linguistically to represent the antithesis of this dissonance.

Answer (score 1):

A groove also refers to a repetitive pattern. Something habitual and comfortable, and therefore pleasant.  Brad is correct about the groove in vinyl, it engendered the the 60's/70's adjective "groovy" The most likely evolution here is from groovy as an adjective, to groove as verb.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the groove in vinyl gave rise to the word groovy? The expression in the groove was used by jazz musicians in the 1930s, and I can imagine etymologies for that which have nothing to do with vinyl records. I can also see how this expression might be derived from vinyl records.

Answer (score 1):

Although this term was used by earlier jazz cats, and can also mean being cool with the music or the scene, the double entendre type of use in the sixties also meant having sex with your girl or guy, a common recreation in the sixties!

Answer (score -1):

I would think that "groove" as used in "in the groove" would have its source in groove music which may be understood as music that generally "swings" thereby being pleasurable. It is interesting that "groove" as used in music has its roots in the original meaning of groove as mentioned by you in your question, i.e., to make grooves- which is in a rhythmic pattern. So is the case of "groovy" music that is "carefully aligned concurrent rhythmic patterns" that sets in motion dancing or foot-tapping on the part of listeners (source http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groove_(music)).